# Get or fetch Latest or last create multiple rows in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am in need of desperate help. I am newbie to laravel and programming.

I have a sales controller which fetch multiple records from form using jquery and select.

Sales Store controller looks like:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < count($request['product_id']); ++$i) 
     {
     $sales= new Sale;        
                $sales->product_id = $request['product_id'][$i];
                $sales->qty= $request['qty'][$i];
                $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $sales->save(); 
                $product = new Product;
                $product->where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i]);

            }
```

this code is working perfectly fine.

Now the scenario is that I want to fetch these last created specific records to send it somehow to other page or as an invoice. Any help will be greatly appreciated on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes I do have time-stamps. These row will be added dynamically by the sales man. If he sales only one product it should get one product, if it has multiple products suppose 3, then the Sale::limit(5) will pull the unnecessary 2 other fields as well.

Comment: so you need only sales?? or with product too?? or only product??

Comment: I want the sales and the products as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `new array` to hold the `sales and product` data and `redirect` to your `desired url` with that `data`.

```
$data = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($request['product_id']); ++$i) 
 {
     $sales= new Sale;        
     $sales->product_id = $request['product_id'][$i];
     $sales->qty= $request['qty'][$i];
     $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $sales->save(); 
     $product = new Product;
     $product->where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i]);
     $data[]['sales'] = $sales;
     $data[]['product'] = $product;

 }
return redirect("/your desired url")->with('data', $data);
```

For your second question in the comment, In your `controller` function of your desired `url` do this -

```
$data = [];
if ($request->session()->has('data')) {
    $data = $request->session()->get('data');
}

return view('your view', compact('data'));
```

And then in your view -

```
@foreach($data as $d)
    {{$d['sales']}}  //here $d['sales'] is your sales object
    {{$d['product']}} //here $d['product'] is your product object
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Can you please guide me how to display this data in a view?

Comment: Thank You. But i'm getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad see my updated answer, it should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you again. It's redirecting me back to sales.index, I don't know why?.
$data = [];
     if ($request->session()->has('data')) {
        $data = $request->session()->get('data');
    }
    return view('admin.invoice.index', compact('data'));

Comment: i don't know too as it is pretty unclear, may be you could make a new question with updated code of controller and view,l that way others can help you

Comment: Thank You @ Sohel0415, for your precious time and help it should have worked, but anyway I will post the updated version as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$sales = Sale::latest()->take(count($request['product_id']))->get();
```

`latest()` will just order all the sales by the date of creation in descending order.

if `count($request['product_id'])` is 5, `take()` will fetch the first 5 sales.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Sale::latest()->first(); will only fetch the last row. Please read my above comment. Thank You.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope I have now answered your question

Comment: Your query is logically right. And thanks for your respone.
I have added it, after 
$sales->save();
$lastSale = Sale::latest()->take(count($request['product_id']))->get();

 return view('admin.sales.invoice', compact('lastSale'));

but i'm getting a blank white page. It's not even loading the layout. Can you please help?